# Why is this gradle task missing sources?

Tags: gradle

Gradlew newb here, trying to figure out why when I invoke my task it's missing it's expected sources. I was under the impression that the tasks are executing in the correct order based on `gradle explodeJars --info`

```
$ gradle explodeJars --info
...
:copyJarsOver (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.051 secs.
:explodeJars (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
:explodeJars
Skipping task ':explodeJars' as it has no source files.
:explodeJars UP-TO-DATE
:explodeJars (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
```

The tasks in question:

```
task copyJarsOver(type: Copy, dependsOn: ["buildAll"]) {
  from 'some/folder/cool.jar'
  from 'another/folder/fancy.jar'
  from 'best/folder/awesome.jar'
  into 'build/modules'
  rename { String fileName ->
    fileName.replace('.jar', '.zip')
  }
}

// Explodejars doesn't work when first ran, works second time <?>
task explodeJars(type: Copy, dependsOn: ["copyJarsOver"]) {
  fileTree(dir: 'build/modules').each({ zipModule ->
    def module = zipTree(zipModule)
    from module
  })
  into 'build/explodedJars'
}
explodeJars.mustRunAfter copyJarsOver
```

Comment: Wound up fixing it by just changing my explodesJar task to use a series of _from_'s but I'm still interested in why this solution didn't work out as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I got confused about the life-cycle of the tasks...

Code inside the task gets executed at configuration time - at which point the files haven't been copied to the folder yet. If I wanted it ran at execution time I should've put it in a doLast.

Either way, from accepts a closure like: `from { fileTree(...).collect { zipModule -> zipTree(zipModule) } }`